# Preview question is not working via the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, asking-questions

When I tried to add a question on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/tour) via the Stack Exchange Android app, I clicked on the preview button to get the preview of question, but it showed nothing.

- Android version: 5.0.2

Comment: I just tried it on Nexus 5, Android 7.1.2 (Lineage OS 14), and it works.. could you also mention the device model? Note however that the development on SE mobile apps is halted indefinitely.

Comment: I am using Lenovo A6010, Android 5.0.2. I just tried now, it's working. I don't know what happened The last time.

Comment: I think the API backend of Stack Exchange had a problem when you wrote your question, so the preview and tagging didn't return any result.